# Where to use deltaTime in jump calculation (C#, MonoGame)

Tags: c#, monogame, frame-rate

I've built a platform game and I'm in the process of trying to make it independent of frame rate by using deltaTime. I'm struggling to find how to use it in my jump calculation though. In order to have a variable jump, I increase the variable `jumpForce` by 1 every update for as long as the jump button is held down by the player. Using the expression below, the increasing `jumpForce` decelerates the player over time (gravity is pulling the player in the opposite direction):

```
v2Speed += new Vector2(0, -(jumpHeight * 10) / (0.1f + (jumpForce * 3)));
```

However I can't find where to use deltaTime. I thought maybe I needed to increase jumpForce by an amount multiplied by deltaTime, but that doesn't give the same height of jump for any frame rate. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you want you code to be independent of Framerate, put any physics-related calculations in `FixedUpdate` (and use Time.fixedDeltaTime multiplied by a "per second" value). E.g. in `Update` determine if the button is pressed, set a bool and check that bool in `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it without FixedUpdate? I've managed to make the player's horizontal movement independent just by multiplying the speed by deltaTime when adding it to the player position.

Comment: That works because speed *is* distance over time. If you change the speed over time (acceleration) you have to either calculate the position with a regard for acceleration or approximate it in a fixed interval (`FixedUpdate`). Judging by your explanation I take it you don't use the built-in physics engine?